# session not working properly in php

Tags: php, session

I have a problem with session. 
I have 3 php pages login, home and edit. 
When i login session is created successfully and goes to home. 
In home I have a link which goes to edit. 
But when i go to edit the session is unset. 
I tried to echo session value in both pages. 
It successfully shows session value in home but not in edit. 
What might be the problem?
Please help.

login.php

```
   if($countStudent == 1){
     $_SESSION['stuName']= $username;
    header("location:studenthome.php");
```

home.php

```
   <?php
   error_reporting(0);
   session_start();
   if(!isset($_SESSION['stuName'])) {
   echo "Click here to <a href=\"index.php\">Re-LogIn</a>";
   }

    else if(isset($_POST['logout']))
   {
   unset($_SESSION['stuName']);
    header('Location: index.php');

   }
  else if(isset($_POST['edit']))
   {
    header('Location: edit.php');

   }
    ?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"          
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>Untitled Document</title>
     </head>
    <body>
   <div id="container">
    <?php
   if (isset($_SESSION['stuName'])) {
   ?>
     <form id="studenthome" action="studenthome.php" method="post"/>
   <div id="menubar">
    <input type="submit" name="logout" value="Logout" />
    <input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit Profile" />
    </form>
   </div>
    <?php
       }
    ?>
  </body>
   </html>
```

upto this everything is working fine.

edit.php

```
    session_start();
     if(!isset($_SESSION['stuName'])) {
    echo "Click here to <a href=\"index.php\">Re-LogIn</a>";
    }
```

Comment: You are remembering to session_start() in all pages, right?  You might want to share some code if you want any specific help.

Comment: please post the code that, you are using to start the session's on each of the pages !

Comment: can you post the code of the page(s) which you suspect that the session is not working on? Also do check on @Gordon's comment above

Comment: home.php loads fine but in edit.php it shows Click here to Re-Login

Comment: Try this code on edit.php     <?php
echo "Student Name=". $_SESSION['stuName'];
?>

Comment: so there a problem in storing sesstion ok now try this code in home.php

Comment: Does login.php not call session_start()?  You have to start a session to write it as well as to read it.

Comment: working fine in home.php

Comment: GordonM: yes i have it in login.php. the problem is actually inbetween home.php and edit.php

Comment: also add <?php echo $username; ?> in login.php page and see if its null or having value.

Comment: Whenever there is `header('Location: ...` think `exit();` as well. This might not fix your problem but probably spares you the one or other headache.

Comment: hakre: can u be more specific

Comment: Read this manual page, understand it. Go there again, read **all Notes** on that page again. Understand them all. Come back: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Please tell me how you reach edit.php from home.php

Comment: jolly.exe: Using button. if(isset($_POST['button'])){header....}

Comment: ..isset($_POST['button'])){header...  Plz add this thing in home.php

Comment: got it working. just retyped the whole code of edit.php and now working fine. Anyway thanks guys. Jolly: tried ur code too. Its working now . thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following example and its working fine see if it solves your problem

**login.php**

```
<?php session_start(); 
     $_SESSION['stuName']= "jolly";
 ?>
<a href="home.php">home</a>
```

**home.php**

```
<?php
   session_start();
?> 

<?php
echo "Student name=". $_SESSION['stuName'];
?>

<a href="edit.php">edit </a>
```

**edit.php**

```
<?php
   session_start();
   echo $_SESSION['stuName'] ;
?>
```

It will not be explanatory in comments so I used answer to explain :P

Comment: Hey what is "community wiki" and who did this ? is this happens automatically :p

Comment: You clocked a checkbox, when you posted the answer, most likely by pressing *tab, tab, space*.

Comment: tereško: i meant it shows the same message(click here to relogin)

Answer (score 0):

Probably `session.save_path` is not writable or doesn't exists.
Check your save path in `php.ini` and than check if it exists.

Also check if you have `session_destroy()` in any file.

EDIT: Use `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at top of your script for possible errors in your script.